# Node.js catching async errors with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I feel like I'm going overboard here and need a sanity check, I am using jest with SuperTest

Q1) If the expect `expect(res.status).toBe(400);` fails will the catch block fire?

Q2) Should I `throw error` or `throw New Error()`

Q3) Does jest just handle this and I don't need a try catch statement?

```
const testUrl = '/register';
const headers = ['Accept', 'application/json'];

it('should validate that the `email` has already been registered and throw 400 error', async (done) => {
    try {
        const res = await request(app).post(testUrl).set(headers).send({
            email: 'test@myDomain.com',
            fullName: 'test user',
            password: 'testPassword!',
        });
        expect(res.status).toBe(400);
        expect(res.body.message).toEqual('You have already registered');
    } catch (error) {
        error.message = `${error.message}\n\nfailing query: ${testUrl}`;
        throw error;
    } finally {
        done();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use supertest's helper methods? And no, you don't need most of what you've posted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you have an example you could point me at?

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest - multiple examples showing their expect method, and the whole thing is a promise.